# Can Atopica capsules for dogs be given to cats?

Tags: cats, medicines

I struggle getting Atopica liquid into my cat so my vet game me the capsules for dogs, but I read on the package it only meant to be used for dogs.  Is it safe for my cat?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is safe, it's the exact same drug only difference is cats have liquid form whereas dogs have capsules/tablets.

People tend to find it easier to give liquids vs pills to cats.

If you want more peace of mind than from an internet stranger you can give the company a call and talk to their staff 1-888-545-5973 (US Elanco) 
Website - https://www.elanco.us/contact-us/default.aspx